# Socket.io EADDRNOTAVAIL error

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I oppened port of 120 on my firewall and i open ufw port on my server (Ubuntu 16.04)
But when run this code ;

```
 var app = require('express')();
var http = require( "http" ).createServer( app );
 var io = require( "socket.io" )( http );
 http.listen(120, "xxxx.xxx.xx");


 io.on('connection',function(socket){
 console.log("A user is connected");
 });
```

I get this error ;

```
 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL xxxx.xxxxxx:120
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1224:19)
    at listen (net.js:1273:10)
    at net.js:1382:9
    at nextTickCallbackWith3Args (node.js:452:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:358:17)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:444:11)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be that port 120 is already being used by something else.

You can use netstat to see what is listening on that port:

```
sudo netstat -plnt | grep ':120'
```

Another thing to mention is that low ports are sometimes reserved or blocked - you may want to just try a higher port, '1337' is always good for NodeJS :-)

Comment: I get some error sir. I tryed 3000 port . but i get some error too :( This code block worked on Digital Ocen but doesn't work on Microsoft azure..

Comment: One thing too when i write sudo netstat -plnt | grep ':120' i didn't get anything